# Add Prerender.io to Existing angularJS webapp

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, prerender

Ive been trying to setup my Angular webApp to work with [prerender.io](https://prerender.io/) however my app does not have any of the built in middleware they desire; I have decided I want to work with [express.js](http://expressjs.com/) as most the tutorials set up the project using this.

[Example setup](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/11/prerender-angularjs-apps-boost-seo/)

I am able to create a project that works with prerender if I make it new using the express.js generator plugin. Thats all good and dandy but it doesn't really help me out; as I am not creating a project, rather I want to add prerender to my existing project. Is there a way to create a new express.js project and import an entire angular app (with all folder structure; etc, basically moving the app's root directory over to the new express app)into it and have all the routing etc be unaffected?

How would one go about adding Prerender to an already created angularJS webapp? (like the basic one seen below) I've tried a bunch of times throughout the day and just ended up installing a ton of ugly dependancies into my project and having to delete them all; any help is appreciated. ::

app.js:

// app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myPremadeApp', ['ngRoute']) 

$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){ 

  $routeProvider.when('/', { 
    templateUrl : 'views/homeView.html', 
    controller: 'homeController' 
  })
  .when('/about', {
      templateUrl : '/views/aboutView.html',
      controller: 'aboutController'
  })
  .when('/features', {
      templateUrl : '/views/featuresView.html',
      controller : 'featuresController'
  })
  .otherwise({
          redirectTo : '/'
  });

});

function mainController($scope) { 

  $scope.seo = { 
    pageTitle : '', pageDescription : '' 
  }; 
}

function homeController($scope) { 

  $scope.$parent.seo = { 
    pageTitle : 'setup the thing', 
    pageDescripton: 'stuff for description' 
  }; 
}

function aboutController($scope) { 
  $scope.$parent.seo = { pageTitle : 'About', 
    pageDescripton: 'We are a content heavy website so we need to be indexed.' 
  }; 
}

function featuresController($scope) { 
  $scope.$parent.seo = { pageTitle : 'Features', pageDescripton: 'Check out some of our awesome features!' }; 
}
```

Comment: How are you currently serving your angularjs app from the server side? You shouldn't have to do a lot of changing things. You just need to get the middleware installed somewhere in your stack.

Comment: looking into something now; will update tomorrow if successful

Comment: Feel free to email me at todd@prerender.io if you need any help. Happy to help!

Comment: We got it working; which was a horrific process to do on an IIS server (which had to be done since the website is not the only thing run on port 80 in my company so I couldn't just run off express or other middleware). Someone online has figured a way to hack prerender.io for IIS and I would suggest adding it to the options on the company page as the "fast and easy" setup ONLY works if the website is the only thing on port 80. I almost ended up just writing my own prerender with phantom.js because it was so complex getting it to work. seems nice for simple setups; complex ones its a disaster.